# (python)pmdarima.auto_arima(pyramid.auto_arima) won't use d and D args automatically

Tags: python, time-series, pyramid-arima

I manually made 20 models and found out **should use `d=1` or `D=1` for each model**, but **`auto_arima` never use difference args**(even one model has no `d` or `D` at all, and all of the trials are like (1,0,1) x (0, 0, 1, 52). I checked it by setting `trace=True`).

I want `auto_arima` to do params grid search **`pdq=(0~3, 0~1, 0~3)` and `PDQs=(0~3, 0~1, 0~3, 52)`**.

I set params as below:

```
    start_p=0,
    start_q=0,
    max_p=3,
    max_d=1,
    max_q=3,
    start_P=0,
    D=None,
    start_Q=0,
    max_P=2,
    max_D=1,
    max_Q=2,
    max_order=10,
    m=52,
    seasonal=True,
    stationary=False,
    information_criterion='aic',
    alpha=0.05,
    test='kpss',
    seasonal_test='ocsb',
    stepwise=True,
    n_jobs=-1,
    start_params=None,
    trend=None,
    method=None,
    transparams=True,
    maxiter=None,
    n_fits=100,
    with_intercept=True,
```

How to make `auto_arima` do grid search what I wanna do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several thing you should know about `pmdarima` and its implementation of `auto_arima`. I'm playing a bit with that at the moment so I will try to answer your questions.

1. **Grid search**: The implementation of `auto_arima` use stepwise algorithm to identify optimal parameters. It's `stepwise` in your params above which is set to `True` by default. In the [API](https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.AutoARIMA.html) there is written:

   > The stepwise algorithm can be significantly faster than fitting all hyper-parameter combinations and is less likely to over-fit the model.

   If you want to make grid search, you have to set this parameter to `False`.
2. **Differencing parameters**: When you try this option (`stepwise=False`), it should try all the combinations except two params - `d` and `D`. That's because they are estimated and not included in params search. In params listed in your questions you have two tests - `test` and `seasonal_test`. These methods are used to select values for `d` and `D` respectively.

   I would recommend you to read documentation on [Understanding p, d and q](https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/tips_and_tricks.html#understand-p-d-and-q). You can get a bit better idea how they deal with differencing parameter estimation.

   You can also try to test these method directly (just change the value of test):

```py
from pmdarima.arima.utils import ndiffs
ndiffs(y, test='kpss')
```

I don't know about how to test `d` params in grid search, I think both Python and R implementation do the same or similar estimation. Therefore, you can do that by yourself and run `auto_arima` with manually set differencing parameters and leave rest on grid search. Otherwise it will select values for both `d` and `D` automatically. The question is - how do you know each model should use `d=1` and `D=1` when those automatic tests say something different?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I was confused with is that based on AIC, the model should use D=1, d=1(I manually made a model by `statsmodels` and got a good AIC score), but `auto-arima` wouldn't use that params and returns the best params eg. D=0, q=0, even though AIC diff(former 800 vs later 2100) is large. Hence I am curious why `auto-arima` wouldn't use that params.

Comment: I think the reason for that is that `auto_arima` focus on differencing parameter (`d`) estimation at first (in your case selected by `kpss` test) and than it tries to auto fit the rest (`p` and `q`) choosing it by selected `information_criterion` which is AIC in your case. If you really want full grid search you will probably have to do it by yourself. Either follow what I wrote in the answer or even write it completely as it's explained [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-grid-search-sarima-model-hyperparameters-for-time-series-forecasting-in-python/)